# Handler to sms ContentObserver

Tags: android, sms, contentobserver

I have found this code in two posts here:

```
String url = "content://sms/"; 
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url); 
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(uri, true, new MyContentObserver(handler));
```

But I don't know what this handler passed in the constructor of MyContentObserver is.

I want to register a ContentObserver in "content://sms//sent" to be notified when Android sends a sms, and in the documentation of ContentObserver says that the method OnChange will be called from the handled passed in the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Handler` is used in conjunction with a `Looper` to execute a queue of tasks one by one. In the case of a ContentObserver, its `onChange()` method might be called multiple times. To queue these calls and execute them sequentially, you need to supply a handler.

If you want `onChange()` to be executed in the main thread, simply create a new Handler like: `Handler handler = new Handler();` and pass it.

But if you want `onChange()` to be executed in another thread, you first need to create a `Looper` for that thread using `Looper.prepare();`

The reason you don't need to create a `Looper` for the main thread is that it is automatically created for you.

For a nice explanation of how Handler & Looper work, check [this article](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/).

Comment: I still didn't understand why ContentObserver constructor should pass a Handler while the Handler object is useless in the class.